# SharedPreferences not saving after restart

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My sharedPreferences does not persist after I close the app. It always leaves the default 4 that I add the first time the app runs.

```
        static public Boolean addFavoriteItem(Integer itemId, Context c) {
    SharedPreferences s = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    Set<String> list = new HashSet<>();
    list = s.getStringSet("favItems",list);
    list.add(Integer.toString(itemId));
    s.edit().putStringSet("favItems",list).apply();
    Log.d("listNowAdd:",list.toString());
    return true;
}
static public Boolean removeFavoriteItem(Integer itemId, Context c) {
    SharedPreferences s = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    Set<String> list = new HashSet<>();
    list = s.getStringSet("favItems",list);
    list.remove(Integer.toString(itemId));
    s.edit().putStringSet("favItems",list).apply();
    Log.d("listNowRemove:",list.toString());
    return true;
}
```

It does work temporarily, even after the activity is restarted, but not after the app is closed and reopened, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot modify the `StringSet` returned by `SharedPreferences` as [documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)):

> Note that you *must not* modify the set instance returned by this call. The consistency of the stored data is not guaranteed if you do, nor is your ability to modify the instance at all.

Essentially what happens is that you're modifying the `Set` owned by `SharedPreferences`. It "works" while the app is running since the same (modified by you) `Set` is kept in memory. When you're trying to save the changes, shared preferences implementation compares the values using `equals()` and of course the set is equal with itself, and therefore no changes are actually saved.

You can create a new `Set<String>` e.g. `HashSet<String>` and `addAll()` the set you retrieved from shared preferences and do your modifications on this copy.